# Python Package from Library Compiler: Matlab Runtime Error: Index exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: python, python-2.7, matlab, matlab-compiler

I have a function in Matlab. I created a python package from it to use in my python code. So far so good. When i call the function in python i received the message:

> MatlabRuntimeError: An error occurred when evaluating the result from a function. Details: 
>                 File C:\Users\Roberto\AppData\Local\Temp\Guilherme\mcrCache9.0.1\classi4\classificado\contagemWGS84.m, line 59, in contagemWGS84
>               Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

when i go to the line 59 of my code:

```
plantas(1) = dados{1}(1);  %line 59
plantas(1).Diameter = ...
    2*sqrt((dados{1}(1).Area*res^2)/pi) + 2*step_erode(1)*res;
for i=1:length(dados)
...
...
...
```

where dados is an 8x1 struct, dados{1} is a 99x1 struct, and dados{1}(1) is a 1x1 struct  matrix and numeric fields. When i run the exact same code directy in matlab, it runs with no problem. When i run in python i got this error.

I am using python 2.7 and Matlab R2016a.
Please help.

Comment: Your problem might be that for a vector of dimension n, indices run from 0 - n-1 in Python and from 1 - n in Matlab.

Comment: i used library compiler from the apps tab in matlab so i think it handle this problem. If i change it the code will be unreadable from the matlab.

Answer (score -1):

Python (and most numpy) arrays are **zero** indexed so accessing memeber[1][1] of a 1x1 matrix is asking for the **second** column of the **second** row.